# yii2 изменить базу данных запросса

Tags: php, yii2

**Будьте любезны, подскажите**

**Как изменить db (базу данных) в Query Builder?**

*Пример:*

```
$q1 = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select([
        "col1",
        "col2",
        "col3"
    ])
    ->from('table1');

$q2 = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select([
       "col1",
       "col2",
       "col3"
    ])
    ->from('table2');

$query=$q1->union($q2);

$query = \Yii::$app->db2->createCommand($query);

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
]);
```

Запрос выполняется для базы которая db.
Получаю **"Object of class yii\db\Query could not be converted to string"**

**Благодарю за ответы**

Comment: запрос вы выполняете для `db2` ......вы смотрели что у вас возвращает запрос?

Answer (score 1):

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'db'=>\Yii::$app->db2,
]);
```

---

```
$arr=$query->all(\Yii::$app->db2);
$dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
            'allModels'=>$arr,
]);
```

http://www.yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?t=16210

Comment: Подскажите,  это ответ или дополнение?